# How to fix 401 unauthorized status when logged in using the postman

Tags: reactjs, jwt

I have problem regarding to these 401 Unauthorized status, I don't know why it gives that status when I try to test my Authentication login to the postman,

I just watching what the video is doing

[Bitfumes JWT Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l201RSQ7Ti4)

**This is my table in my database**

[image: Sample Table]

**This my postman:**

[image: My Postman]

**The login function gives me response of error.**

```
public function login()
{
    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

    if (! $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }

    return $this->respondWithToken($token);
}
```

Comment: Did you set the API middleware as the default? If not, do that. If you don't want to change your default middleware than do this: `auth('api')->attempt($credentials)`

Comment: where can i find that?

Comment: If you look at the code snipper you posted you can see the attempt method as the if statement. If API is not your default middleware then just change the middleware in the auth method like the one I just posted. The documentation is a great place to debug your code.

Comment: your suggestion same error.

Comment: Ah, sorry my bad. Wrong method. Try this instead `$token = auth()->guard('api')->attempt($credentials);` I have this in my code and it works perfectly

Comment: same error, i think my password not encrypted properly , do you know how to encrypt the password properly

Answer (score 1):

Since this question contains multiple errors I'll just write it all up as an answer.

You probably don't have the api guard set up as the default middleware.
To fix that, change the middleware (he also does that in the video) which is also described in the documentation (https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start/) in the `Configure Auth guard` part.

If you don't want to change your default guard then just change your attempt method like this: `$token = auth()->guard('api')->attempt($credentials);`

With your code this will still result in an error because you're defining the token variable inside the if statement. So just define the token outside of the if statement and use it. This is the complete edited version of your code.

```
public function login()
{
    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

    $token = auth()->guard('api')->attempt($credentials);

    if (!$token) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Incorrect credentials'], 401);
    }

    return $this->respondWithToken($token);
}
```

Comment: even i try to configure that, it gives Incorrect credentials, I don't know why is it because I use the md5 hash generator to create password thats why it gives wrong credential

Comment: Do you use Laravel? Laravel uses bcrypt as its encryption. Not md5

Comment: @DevGe, if my answer helped you out. Please accept it so people will know it works in the future.

Comment: sorry rick for the delay of response, I got busy. for that thank you for your suggestion to me. the solution that I did is to change my password in database and make the password use as bcrypt..